# Searching/Sorting Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I've created a multi-dimensional array based on the x/y coords of the perimeter of a circle.  An object can be dragged along the arc (in javascript) and then 'dropped' anywhere on it.  The problem is, I need to find the closest x and y coordinate to where the object is 'dropped.'

My current solution involves looping through an array and finding the closest value to x, and then looping again to find the y coordinate, but it doesn't seem very clean and there are problems with it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try working with an angle and find out the X and Y using sin and cos

Comment: Are the x and y coordinates in the array evenly spaced?

Comment: @OmerPT, I've already got the angle worked out, thanks though.

Comment: @Jeremy, what do you mean by "are the x & y coords evenly spaced?"  @Michael, I'd post my code but I don't think it's necessary (and it's a tad long).  :) I was just hoping someone had an idea about how i could go about retrieving the nearest [x,y] value from the array. It can be a high-level explanation...basically, I was just wondering what the alternatives are.

Comment: Let's say you have a 500x500 pixel square, and you have a 6x6 array, where each point is 100 pixels apart, i.e. (0,0), (0,100), (0,200), etc. Then you could easily just calculate the closest one without having to iterate through the array.

Comment: @user - have you done the trig per @Omer's suggestion? Would be ridiculously faster.  Trig the numbers, then round or adjust according to your requirements (sort of what @Jeremy is saying).

Answer (score 1):

So, let's see. We assume a predefined set of (x, y) coordinates. You are given another point and have to find the *nearest* element of the array to that given point. I am going to assume "nearest" means the smallest Pythagorean or Euclidean distance from the given point to each of the other points.

The simplest algorithm is probably the best (if you want to look at others in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_point_query), have at it). Since you didn't give us any code for the structure, I'm going to assume an array of objects, each object having an `x` and a `y` property, ditto for the given point.

```
var findNearestPoint = function (p, points) {
  var minDist = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
      minPoint = -1,
      i,
      l,
      curDist,
      sqr = function(x) { return x * x; };

  for (i = 0, l = points.length; i < l; i++) {
    curDist = sqr(p.x - points[i].x) + sqr(p.y - points[i].y);
    if (curDist < minDist) {
      minDist = curDist;
      minPoint = i;
    }
  } 
  return points[i];
};
```

(Untested, but you get the idea.)

Comment: boyetboy, wanted to say thanks for the above reply, it gave me direction with my code...much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If your arrays are created in sequential order (that is from smallest to greatest or greatest to smallest), you could use introduce a Binary Search Algorithm.

1. Get middle element of x array.
2. If x equals your value, stop and look for y, otherwise.

   1. If x is lower, search in the lower half of the array (starting from step 1).
   2. If x is higher, search in the upper half of the array (starting from step 1).

Then use the same formula on y. You might have to change to algorithm a bit to make it so it works with the closest matching element. Having not seen your array, I can't offer code to solve to problem.

Comment: MillsJROSS, wanted to thank you for your reply, it was very helpful!